# Jest unit tests fail when changing from shallow to mount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test some life cycle functions in React such as `componentWillUnmount` so my understand is that I will need to use `mount` instead of `shallow` as shallow will not render child components or the life cycle functions

Currently I have this which works fine

```
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

wrapper = shallow(
    <Component />
)

afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
});

it("should render page correctly.", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('form').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

And this is working fine ... I then change `wrapper = shallow` to `wrapper = mount` as so

```
wrapper = mount(
    <Component />
)
```

And my test now fails ... and I receive the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

I can't figure out why this would be, maybe my understanding of what mount and shallow are is wrong? Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Show the code of the component.